# Backing up a reasonable number of GB online

Tags: backup, cloud-storage

I am considering backing up my files to the cloud or quite simply just online. I know free services are few but exist. The thing is I want a truly free service where I can upload at least 100GB or a bit more or less.

I am familiar with most of the paid services but If anyone out there has a solution to a free service or if there is a better solution that you might have let me know.

Comment: If you have very important stuff, make multiple physical copies; don't just rely on some cloud service. See [The Computer Backup Rule of Three](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheComputerBackupRuleOfThree.aspx).

Comment: We are jogging to be unable to suggest free services

Comment: If backing up your data doesn't isn't valuable enough to pay for, why do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

China has some free crazy cloud storage options: [2TB](http://www.taigeair.com/how-to-get-2tb-with-baidu-pan-disk-for-free-for-life/) or [10TB](http://www.weiyun.com/act/10t-en.html?WYTAG=weiyun.portal.index). I think [Russia](https://www.ozbargain.com.au/node/128714) had a similar 1TB deal, but I think mail.ru is down to 100GB now.

Apart from that, free storage is limited. [mega.co.nz](http://mega.co.nz) offers 50GB storage and its easy to signup for more then one account (using [mailinator.com](http://mailinator.com) for instance). But I don't know how easy it is to use more then one account at the same time.

Now don't take this as a recommendation in any way, those are just the free options you have